# Optimise loading large dataset to a table in asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating asp.net mvc 4 application, In that application I'm loading many rows to a table.

However this function working smoothly for small and average data sets which means if number of rows less to 1000 or less to 5000 this is loading with average time

This view of that table

[image]

But when the number of rows going high which means more than 5000 this take too much time to load those all rows into table

Here the LINQ query that is use to load values to table

```
public ActionResult StudentIndex()
{
    return View(db._student.Where(x => x.Create_By == userid).OrderByDescending(s => s.Create_Date).ToList());

}
```

Here once it load values to table , using Jquery Table sorter function it is doing pagination function , I ignored sorting.

This is jquery script code snippet

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#table-hover")
            .tablesorter({
                widthFixed: true
            })
            .tablesorterPager({
                container: $("#pager"),
                size: $(".pagesize option:selected").val()
            });
    });

 </script>
```

How can I speed up loading for large data-set ? what are the method should I follow?

Comment: Don't try to load so many records at once. There are better plugins ([DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) being one I'm familiar with) that have support for server-side paging. There's also the [WebGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid.aspx) helper.

Comment: As I understood this , once it is fetch total number of rows tablesorter plugin divide those result in portion of 10 , then its present values , that why its take too much time to load for large data sets.

Comment: In a nutshell, you're trying to fetch too much data. Implementing paging on the server is the only way you'll be able to fix this long term. EntityFramework has Skip() and Take() methods you can use for pulling chunks of records instead of a whole table.

Comment: If I use EntityFramework  Skip() or Take() method will I able to pull chunk of 10 by 10 ?

Comment: You use them both together, as they map to the (roughly) equivalent SQL commands. Skip() moves the cursor to the relevant row, and then Take() "selects" the specified number of rows; it basically is the TOP or LIMIT and OFFSET clauses, depending on the underlying SQL system in use.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest go by server side pagination :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part

OR

Working sample 
https://github.com/johannes-brunner/DataTables-ASP.NET-MVC